# Why doesn't tkinter free the thread once the window has closed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a class, ClientGUI (make in tkinter), which represents the client's class for my application. In this class, upon pressing a button, a new tkinter window is opened (using a module I imported), which represents a UI for a drawing tool. When I close this drawing tool window, I want it to return a message to the client class that the drawing tool has been closed. The problem is that I receive this message only when I close the main client window as well. The code for all this is below:

This is the code that declares and starts the main client window:

```
root = Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("Client")
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", onX)
clientGui = clientGUI(root) //clientGUI is the client class. It contains all the UI and functionality elements
root.mainloop()
```

This is the function I use to close it:

```
def onX():
    answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Quit", "Are you sure you want to quit the application ?")

    if answer == "yes":
        root.destroy()
```

In the clientGUI, upon pressing a button, a new window is opened from a module I created, this is the code that starts the new window:

```
def startDrawingTool(self, username, password):

    drawingToolStatus = drawingTool.startTool() // the new window is opened here
    print(drawingToolStatus) // This only gets printed when I close the main client window(clientGui)
```

This is the startTool() function, declared in the drawingTool module I imported:

```
def startTool():
    def onX():
        answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Quit", "Quiting without saving may result in data loss, make sure to always save first. Are you sure you want to quit?")
        if answer == "yes":
            root.destroy()

    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.title("Drawing program")
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", onX)
    app = Application(root) // Application is the drawing tool class, contains all the UI elements and functionality
    root.mainloop()

    return "window closed" // This is how I want to let the main client class know that the drawing tool has been closed
```

Hopefully, I have provided all the code that you need to get an idea of the application and the issue I am facing. As I already said, I want to know why the "`print(drawingToolStatus)`" is only printed when the `clientGui` gets closed and it doesn't in face get printed as soon as I close the `drawingTool`.

Also, if you know a better way to have the two communicate, I'm open to improvements as this is the first Python application I work on.

Comment: Your application should only create a Tk() instance *once*. For additional windows, use `toplevel`. Similarly, `root.mainloop()` is the tkinter event loop for the entire GUI, and should only be called once in the program -- regardless of how many modules are imported. Unpredictable results will occur if these principles are not followed, and you're probably seeing these strange behaviors.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as opposed to some parts of your problematic code.